# fopen_s failing only when launching c++ exe through c# windows form

Tags: c#, c++

I'm creating an application that communicates through name pipes a c++ exe and c# Windows Form, I open the c++ exe through c# to make sure the name pipe is created but I started experiencing problems with fopen_s that only occur when launching through the C# code.

I've tried adding the txt file into the C# and the folder containing the C++ exe

```cs
// This is how I run the exe
Process.Start("C:\\Users\\User\\source\\repos\\HelloWorld\\Release\\H3ll0W0rld.exe");
```

```cpp
DWORD LoadTxt(char*** names, DWORD** ids)
{
    DWORD i = 0;
    FILE* fp;

    cout << fopen_s(&fp, "info.txt", "r") << endl;

    if (fopen_s(&fp, "info.txt", "r") == 0)
    {
        char line[64];

        while (fgets(line, 64, fp) != 0)
        {
            DWORD id;
            char name[64];

            if (sscanf_s(line, "%03d %63[^\n]", &id, &name, sizeof(name)) != 2) { continue; }

            *ids = (DWORD*)realloc(*ids, (i + 1) * sizeof(DWORD));
            (*ids)[i] = id;

            *names = (char**)realloc(*names, (i + 1) * sizeof(char*));
            (*names)[i] = _strdup(name);

            i++;
        }

        if (fp) { fclose(fp); }
    }

    return i;
}
```

I expect it to just run smoothly but nothing is loaded from the txt and when printing `fopen_s(&fp, "info.txt", "r")` it returns 0.

Comment: The current directory is probably wrong.

Comment: Wooo! `char*** names` is a bit much. Can I talk you into a `vector` of `string`?

Comment: Why all of the usage of pointers?  And what if `realloc` returns NULL?

Comment: How do you suggest I open the file? @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: I removed that part of my comment.  But the question still stands -- you do not check if `realloc` returns NULL, and honestly, if you're using C++, there is no need to write functions in such a `C`-like fashion, with `realloc`, `strdup`, etc.  We have `std::string`, `std::vector`, etc.

Comment: Okay but the thing is realloc is never reached it stops at if (fopen_s(&fp, "info.txt", "r") == 0) since it returns 2 and I'm wondering why it only happens when launched through the C# form

Comment: @Axen Why are you attempting to open the file twice?  You do it once in the `cout` line, and then you do it again afterwards.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I do it in the cout to see what it returns so I can know when the problem occurs.

Comment: You don't see an issue with opening a file twice?  Why not simply open the file, get the return value, cout that value, and continue from there with the already opened file?  There is no need to open a file twice in succession.

Comment: Yes I suppose that would be the better approach.